# Why do I see error in this code

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, mechanical

```
NewPing sonar(TRIG_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); 

AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ); 
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor3(3, MOTOR34_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4, MOTOR34_1KHZ);
Servo myservo;   

boolean goesForward=false;
int distance = 100;
int speedSet = 0;

void setup() {

  myservo.attach(10);  
  myservo.write(115); 
  delay(2000);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
 int distanceR = 0;
 int distanceL =  0;
 delay(40);

 if(distance<=15)
 {
  moveStop();
  delay(100);
  moveBackward();
  delay(300);
  moveStop();
  delay(200);
  distanceR = lookRight();
  delay(200);
  distanceL = lookLeft();
  delay(200);

  if(distanceR>=distanceL)
  {
    turnRight();
    moveStop();
  }else
  {
    turnLeft();
    moveStop();
  }
 }else
 {
  moveForward();
 }
 distance = readPing();
}

int lookRight()
{
    myservo.write(50); 
    delay(500);
    int distance = readPing();
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(115); 
    return distance;
}

int lookLeft()
{
    myservo.write(170); 
    delay(500);
    int distance = readPing();
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(115); 
    return distance;
    delay(100);
}

int readPing() { 
  delay(70);
  int cm = sonar.ping_cm();
  if(cm==0)
  {
    cm = 250;
  }
  return cm;
}

void moveStop() {
  motor1.run(RELEASE); 
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  motor4.run(RELEASE);
  } 

void moveForward() {

 if(!goesForward)
  {
    goesForward=true;
    motor1.run(FORWARD);      
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.run(FORWARD); 
    motor4.run(FORWARD);     
   for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2) // slowly bring the speed up to avoid loading down the batteries too quickly
   {
    motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
    delay(5);
   }
  }
}

void moveBackward() {
    goesForward=false;
    motor1.run(BACKWARD);      
    motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    motor3.run(BACKWARD);
    motor4.run(BACKWARD);  
  for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2) // slowly bring the speed up to avoid loading down the batteries too quickly
  {
    motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
    delay(5);
  }
}  

void turnRight() {
  motor1.run(FORWARD);
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(BACKWARD);
  motor4.run(BACKWARD);     
  delay(500);
  motor1.run(FORWARD);      
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);      
} 

void turnLeft() {
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);     
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);  
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);   
  delay(500);
  motor1.run(FORWARD);     
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't include the libraries maybe? What is the error you see?

Comment: You asked about "this error", but you didn't include the actual error message

Answer (score 1):

All of the errors I got were "NewPing does not name a type", "AF_DCMOtor does not name a type" and "motor<> was not declared in this scope". I don't see library includes; at least one for NewPing is needed. I don't know where AF_DCMotor is supposed to be declared but, as it is not declared as a type, it leaves all of the motor undefined. Those are the bulk (if not all) of the errors as the code stands now. Add the missing NewPing library do whatever you need to to define AF_DCMotor.

Comment: AF_DCMotor is also a library.

Comment: Makes perfect sense...

Answer (score 0):

It probably needs a library. Looks like you have some kind of AFDC library and did not use it.